# Not able to purge Azure CDN Endpoint using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cdn

I'm using Azure CLI to purge all the contents from Azure CDN endpoint. I got a reference from Microsoft Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cdn/endpoint?view=azure-cli-latest

I'm trying exactly same commands with proper params but it says - "Endpoint(s) not found. Please verify the resource(s), group or it's parent resources exist."

```
az cdn endpoint purge -g <my-resource-group> --profile-name \
<name-of-cdn-profile> --content-paths '/*' --name <cdn-endpoint-name>
```

-**renders the above error**

however, I can see the CDN endpoint when I issue the list command:

```
az cdn endpoint list -g <my-resource-group> --profile-name <cd>n-profile-name>
```

**the above command works fine and returns the endpoint which I'm trying to purge**

Anyone having a similar experience?

TIA!

Comment: I can produce this error, please check the parameter `--name <cdn-endpoint-name>`, It should not suffix like`.azureedge.net`

Comment: amazing! thanks @NancyXiong, it worked. how do I mark that as an answer? :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can produce this error, please check the parameter `--name <cdn-endpoint-name>`, It should not have a suffix like `.azureedge.net`. The endpoint name is the name of the resource which type is `Endpoint` in your resource group.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With above options I was unable to fix it and then I realized a small issue! Below is the option with double quotes rather single quotes fixed it for me!

```
az cdn profile list 
az cdn endpoint purge --resource-group {rg_name} --name {cdn_name} --profile-name {cdn_profile_name} --content-paths "/*"
```